# Vue3.js ) Error: Cannot find module 'firebase'

Tags: firebase, vue.js, web, frontend

I'm using firebase for the first time in vue.js.
After installing firebase using npm, I added it to main.js as follows.

```
//main.js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Router from "./router.js";
// bootstrap
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap";

// firebase
import firebase from "firebase";

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

createApp(App).use(Router).mount("#app");
```

And this is package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^9.6.4",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-carousel-card": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vue3-carousel": "^0.1.35"
  },
```

If I add firebase and run serve it like this, an error that says firebase cannot be found is output.

```
This dependency was not found:

* firebase in ./src/main.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save firebase
```

May I know the cause and solution of this?
Thank you always.

Comment: could you post nvm list result?

Comment: try to run  npm install --save firebase please

Comment: npm ls -remote
@vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.5.15
├── @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.15
├── @vue/cli-service@4.5.15
├── @vue/compiler-sfc@3.2.27
├── babel-eslint@10.1.0
├── bootstrap@5.1.3
├── core-js@3.20.3
├── eslint-plugin-vue@7.20.0
├── eslint@6.8.0
├── firebase@9.6.4
├── vue-carousel-card@2.0.0
├── vue-router@4.0.12
├── vue@3.2.27
└── vue3-carousel@0.1.35

Comment: I already tried "npm install --save firebase" and deleted it and installed it again.

Comment: I've  firebase hosting this project before, can this be a problem? There are no errors in the new project.

Comment: Can you please share yr repo?

Answer (score 4):

You are using "firebase": "^9.6.4" which uses different way of importing.

You can downgrade to firebase 8:

```
npm remove firebase
npm add firebase@^8.10.0
```

But if you want to use firebase 9 you can either use

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app' //v9

firebase.initializeApp({
   ...
})
```

or

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

initializeApp({
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue, and I found a solution : change your firebase version, it'll work.

```
npm remove firebase
npm add firebase@^8.10.0
```